# Android Studio Emulator won't change screen orientation. API17 and 18 won't even boot

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio, emulation, screen-rotation

I'm currently struggling with the Android Emulator provided by Android Studio.
My first problem was, that the Emulator won't change it's screen orientation. So I press Num7 and the device itself rotates by 90°, but the Application itself doesn't. (Not just my own, but all applications).

So I heard that this is a known bug of the 4.4.2 Emulator. So I tried to start a 4.2.2 or 4.3 emulator. But those won't even start. I get the android-boot-animation but that's it. I've waited for as long as 30 minutes for the device to boot.

Any ideas?

Comment: I recommend the genymotion emulator. Its a lot quicker and has more features. Just started using it yesterday

Comment: I read about that too. But since I'm planing to monetize my app, it would be commercial use, and therefore would cost 99$ per year. Which, at the moment, is to much for me.

Answer (score 0):

At least for the "API 17 and 18 won't even boot"-Problem I found a solution. Problem was that I reused a single AVD. I created it as API 19, and later on just changed the target to API 18 and 17.
Apparently you have to create a new AVD if you want to test another API, just changing it in an existing AVD doesn't seem to work.

By the way: In API 17 the screen rotation works properly.